# How to view Android SQLLite database on emulator

Tags: android, database, shell, android-emulator

I've looked at answers to previous questions on this topic, but can't seem to get any of them to work.  I am developing in Eclipse, and running the app on an emulator.

It seems like the simplest approach is to use the `adb` shell in conjunction with the sqlite3 command.  With adb I can see the emulator device.  When I start the adb shell, I see a directory which is where I would expect to find the database:

```
/data/data/com.example.myfirstapp/databases/  (where com.example.myfirstapp is the package name of the app)
```

However, there are no `.db` files in that directory.  There is a file with the same name as the database the app created, but it does not have the `.db` extension.

(I'm pretty sure I am seeing the file system of the emulated device because it does have the directory for my application).

**UPDATE**

After going through all the responses, and accessing the database via adb/sqlite3 and also using DDMD/Sqlite browser, I realized I made a "newbie" mistake in the code:

```
public class MessageOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyFirstApp.db"; 
    public static final String MESSAGE_COLUMN = "message";
    public static final String MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME = "messages";   

    private static final String MESSAGE_TABLE_CREATE = String.format("create table %s (%s TEXT);", MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME, MESSAGE_COLUMN);

    public MessageOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);      
    }
```

By convention, the database name should include the `.db` extension.  Although it works fine without it, the Sqlite browser for Eclipse won't recognize the file.   Hopefully other neophytes like me won't make the same mistake.

Comment: This is your DB. It is not necessary to have .db extension. use sqlite3.exe with it to open it

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: yes that worked, thanks. For some reason, when I first ran the `.tables` command sqlite3 threw an error saying database not found.  Probably I typed the path wrong.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/  <-- This is very good. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you are using Eclipse ... You can go in DDMS perspective, select the db file and view in Sqllite Browser .. as shown below...

> [image]

**EDIT:-**
Forgot to mentioned we require to add the plugin here...

Follow the [link here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

Steps:-

1. Download the [jar file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91846918/sqlite%20manager/com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar)
2. Add the jar file in your eclipse/dropins/  folder
3. Restart Eclipse.. you will notice the icon in DDMS perspective..

Comment: My DDMS tab doesn't have the Sqlite browser icon.  Is this a separate install?

Comment: @SamGoldberg Sorry forgot to mention how to get to see the icon.. updated the answer .. :)

Comment: CRUSADER: I installed Sqlite browser, and now it shows up on the tool bar, but for some reason, it is disabled when I click on the file. I'm guessing it's because the file does not have the `.db` extension?  (I can view the database in the adb shell using `sqlite3` and issue select statements against it, so the database seems to be okay).

Comment: OK. I got it. One thing I didn't realize is that my code didn't follow the convention of adding `.db` to the database name, so the Sqlite browser icon/menu option was disabled when clicking on the file. Now I know better!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what 'David N' told true, but don't forget to click on device which is located at top left corner Devices tab before checking data -> data -> package name -> database name [image]

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, you can use the DDMS tab to view SQLite database.

Go to file explorer -> data -> data -> package name -> database name

You can now push or pull the database...

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, what 'David N' told true, but don't forget to click on device which is located at top left corner Devices tab before checking data -> data -> package name -> database name