# can I see my Sqlite database on firexfox addon?

Tags: android, sqlite

I created sqlite database in eclipse by code. where is my database on computer? can I see database on sqlite manager from mozilla firefox addon?

Comment: are you going to write phonegap application

Comment: follow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521787/2345913)... And yes.. you can see database on sqlite manager from mozilla firefox addon

Comment: @Karthi thanks I research this. but can I determine my database location manually?

Comment: Your database is inside your Android AVD or device. The path to it is usually /data/data/packagename/databases but if you want to get at the path in code, use the getDatabasePath() method. If you want to have the database file actually on your computer, pull it using DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Run the app on a virtual device, then go to DDMS perspective, from there data/data/yourapplication/database/yourdatabasename then pull the db on the your computer and explore it with the mozilla.(Note:To open sqlite database in mozilla you must have to add Sqlite manager add on.)